A Regex to ensure that a string contains at least two words
Given a string of one or more words, I need a regex which returns true if the string contains two or more words - any words.
My current solution is:
([\w\']+ ){1,}
which works on the basis that a one-word string (which has been stripped) won't have a trailing space, implying there must be another word if the string contains a space.
The solution seems quirky and there has to be a better answer.

What do you consider a word, at least a single word character? \w.*\s.*\w https://regex101.com/r/3ATAvR/1

If you are happy with the definition of word which Ruby has built in, you could use a word boundary anchor, (\b\w+\b.*){2}

Please use this regular expression regex = (\p{L}+)(\W+\p{L}+)+ . The regex will ensures that the string has at least two words separated by one or more spaces and also check punctuation between words and accented characters and unicode letters.

Remove the leading ^ because it will not work if your sentence doesn't start with a word character, such as "  Spaces before" has two words, but your pattern won't match it. Also, words can be separated by punctuation (Ex: "Correct! two") so don't use \s+ but \W+. And don't forget to add the unicode flag if not you will not match "Père Noël". Some regex engines, like JavaScript, don't even match accents with \w. You have to use \p{L} instead, to match any letter in any language.

Hi, @PatrickJanser, yes, you are right. I will update the above regex more robust.

@PatrickJanser, I just updated my regex and tested it my side. Do you think it's enough?

If the user doesn't need to capture the words, then remove the first parenthesis. For the second one, make it non-capturing (as it will probably use less resources). This is done by replacing ( )+ by (?: )+. But this is time-consuming, as one single match of the non-word and word sequence will be enough to validate that there are at least 2 words. So the regex can simply stop and there's no need to keep on searching for other non-word and word sequences. \W+ should be replaced by \P{L}. So I think that \p{L}+\P{L}+\p{L}+ should probably be enough.

It will also match A$A

@Thefourthbird the original post lacks clarity, even after your initial inquiry. For instance yes this solution matches "A$A" but it won't match "1 1" which every other solution seems to consider as 2 words. So the question remains "what [does the OP] consider a word".

"o'clock" is two words?

a='hi how are you'

if a.match?(/\w+(\s+\w+)+$/)
  puts "This string contains more than one word"
else
  puts "This string doesn't contain more than one word"
end

Output
This string contains more than one word


I would replace \s+ by \W+. This way you will also match "Great! thanks". Also, enable the unicode flag so that \w+ will match "Noël", containing accents.

It might read better if you used match? instead of =~ and used a non-capture group instead of the capture group.

@CarySwoveland Sure.

A reliable regex that checks for the presence of at least two words, separated by whitespace would be:
^\s*\S+\s+\S+.*$

How it works:
•   The regex ensures that there are at least two words, separated by whitespace, while ignoring leading whitespace.
•   It doesn’t require the string to end in a space or have trailing spaces.


Neither ^\s* nor .*$ are needed.

"check-in" or "user:Olakunle" both contain two words. Don't forget that punctuation can separate words, even if, effectively, one usually puts a space somewhere next to the punctuation. And is "789" considered as a word? It's not very clear in the original question, I admit. But I think that using \w+ and \W+ is safer than doing the opposite with spaces. And I would enable the unicode flag so that \w matches accents also, or even be more precise by replacing \w by \p{L} to only match letters in any language. And \W would become \P{L}.
